# Struggling to recover space after backup deletion on older system

Tags: backup, time-machine, macos, trash

My 2TB external drive (seagate SRD00F2) is refusing to recover space after deleting backups. I've tried a number of things, hoping to find help here, **TYIA**. The older backups were not deleting automatically, possibly due to the age of the drive and machine, so the drive became full some time ago.

I originally tried deleting folders containing the backups from the drive mount itself by date, pulling them into the trash, and then emptying the trash. Each backup folder indicated a little over 250GB, and increasing logically as the folders approached the current date. I deleted some 1.4TB of backups, and the trash icon indicated deleting some 100k+ files. ~However~ some 24 hours later and after restarting both the drive and the machine, no space has reappeared, although the files no longer appear in the folder and the trash has been emptied.

After reading q&a here, I attempted to delete using the TM. The older backups appear here, but cannot be selected for deletion- no right click is available in window for the backups, and the window reads 'Waiting' at the top. I did delete one backup using this method (one sooner than I'd of liked), and within moments, presto, 200+GB freed. I'm very inexperienced using tmutil, but I did try a few command suggestions found here to no avail. Does anyone know of how I might be able to force the machine to recognize that the backups have been deleted? Our one genius bar is scheduled about two weeks out. *Possibly worth noting that this is an ancient machine, circa late 2009, running El Capitan 10.11.6 (part of why I need to deal with backup issues before attempting to upgrade to Sierra etc)

Comment: **Golden rule** Never attempt to delete anything from a Time Machine volume other than via Time Machine or `tmutil`. It just does not do what you think it will do. [Searching for a good earlier QA…] The only app that can fix [older] TM volumes is Disk Warrior.

Comment: @Tetsujin Duly Noted! I wasn't even aware of being able to delete backups through the TM app before reading here. I had thought to trash them as one might any other normal file.

Comment: They're all hard links. The files you see in each day's folder don't really exist, they're 'copies' that take up zero space. It's all based on inodes; pointers to a location - one file can have hundreds of pointers to the same single file on disk. The file is only *actually* deleted once each & every inode instance is deleted. This is why you didn't gain any space.

Comment: Perhaps this is why within TM it indicates that it's 'waiting' on a given backup- I've deleted the pointer?

Comment: You deleted some - at random - but probably not all. That's likely to upset things.

Comment: I think, practically, your choices are - 1) try to fix with Disk Warrior [pricey & not guaranteed to work at this stage] 2) Abandon the historic aspect of your backup & reformat, make a single new TM backup to it. 3) [this would be my choice] Forget TM altogether if you're doing this as belt & braces for an upgrade. Get [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) & make a good single [bootable] backup you can restore from if things go wrong.